# Streamline code, many years of data to process - lapply, raster, stack, mean, crop to AOI

Tags: r, loops, spatial, netcdf, r-raster

I have some code in R which does the following:

1. Uses lapply to bring in files in a set folder e.g. 1997 data
2. Makes file list into a brick - they are NetCDF files, so I've used brick function
3. Stacks the bricks into one raster stack of months for each year.
4. Calculate the mean from the stack
5. Crops the new mean raster to the Area of Interest (AOI).

I've got a working code, **see below**, but it is clunky and I feel could be better in one loop to then run through each year's folder (I have data from 1997 to 2018). Could anyone aid in streamlining this into a simple looped code I could run by changing the filepath? I've used loops a bit before but not from scratch.

```
# Packages:
library(raster)
library(parallel) # Check cores in PC
library(lubridate) # needed for lapply
library(dplyr) # ""
library(sf) # For clipping data
library(rgdal)

# ChlA
  
# Set file paths for input and outputs:
usingfp <- "/filepath/GIS/ChlA/1997/"
the_dir_ex <- "Data/CHL/1997"

# List all NETCDF files in folder:
CHL_1997 <- list.files(path = usingfp, pattern = "\\.nc$", full.names = TRUE, 
                    recursive = FALSE)

# Make file list into brick
CHL_1997_brick <- lapply(CHL_1997,
       FUN = brick,
       the_dir = the_dir_ex)
# Stack bricks
s <- stack(CHL_1997_brick)

# Calculate mean from stack
mean <- calc(s, fun = mean, na.rm = T)
plot(mean)

# Load vector boundary to "crop" to
AOI <- readOGR("/filepath/AOI/AOI.shp")
plot(AOI,
     main = "Shapefile imported into R - crop extent",
     axes = TRUE,
     border = "blue",
     add = T)

# crop the raster using the vector extent
CHL_1997_mean <- crop(mean, AOI)
plot(CHL_1997_mean, main = "Cropped mean CHL - 1997")

# add shapefile on top of the existing raster
plot(AOI, add = TRUE)
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, a very well constructed question, addressed by the author of the `raster` package, and a lot of strategy packed in there. I learned quite a bit from each.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
library(raster)

AOI <- shapefile("/filepath/AOI/AOI.shp")
path <- "/filepath/GIS/ChlA/"
years <- 1997:2018

for (yr in years) {
    fp <- file.path(path, yr)
    fout <- file.path(fp, paste0(year, ".tif"))
    print(fout); flush.console()
    # if (file.exists(fout)) next
    files <- list.files(path=fp, pattern="\\.nc$", full.names=TRUE)
    b <- lapply(files, brick)
    s <- stack(b)
    s <- mean(s)
    s <- crop(s, AOI, filename=fout) #, overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Notes:

- `mean(s)` is more efficient than `calc(s, mean)`
- If the AOI is relatively small, it can be more efficient to first
  use `crop`, then `mean` (and then use `writeRaster`)

You can also use `terra` like this:

```
library(terra)
AOI <- vect("/filepath/AOI/AOI.shp")
path <- "/filepath/GIS/ChlA/"
years <- 1997:2018

for (yr in years) {
    fp <- file.path(path, year)
    fout <- file.path(fp, paste0(year, ".tif"))
    print(fout); flush.console()
    # if (file.exists(fout)) next
    files <- list.files(path=fp, pattern="\\.nc$", full.names=TRUE)
    r <- rast(files)
    s <- mean(r)
    s <- crop(s, AOI, filename=fout) #, overwrite=TRUE)
}
```